# How to extract xml response in php and create json response

Tags: php, arrays, json, xml, xml-parsing

after getting xml response from server using $result = curl_exec($ch);
i want to exctract some data from xml response and build that extracted data to valid json format and send that json to mobile app in android

this is what i am getting from my server.

```
<ENVELOPE>
 <HEADER>
  <VERSION>1</VERSION>
  <STATUS>1</STATUS>
  </HEADER>
 <BODY>
  <DESC>
   <CMPINFO>
    ...
   </CMPINFO>
  </DESC>
  <DATA>
       <COLLECTION ISMSTDEPTYPE="Yes" MSTDEPTYPE="512">
    <STOCKITEM NAME="Abc Test" RESERVEDNAME="">
     <STOCKITEMNAME TYPE="String">Abc Test</STOCKITEMNAME>
     <CLOSINGBALANCE TYPE="Quantity"> 102 Nos</CLOSINGBALANCE>
     <OPENINGBALANCE TYPE="Quantity"> 500 Nos</OPENINGBALANCE>
     <DEBITTOTALS TYPE="Quantity"> 418 Nos</DEBITTOTALS>
     <CREDITTOTALS TYPE="Quantity"> 20 Nos</CREDITTOTALS>
     <OPENINGVALUE TYPE="Amount">-1000000.00</OPENINGVALUE>
     <CLOSINGVALUE TYPE="Amount">-366400.00</CLOSINGVALUE>
     <OUTWARDVALUE TYPE="Amount">4180000.00</OUTWARDVALUE>
     <INWARDVALUE TYPE="Amount">-2400.00</INWARDVALUE>
     <BASICQTY TYPE="Quantity"></BASICQTY>
     <OPENINGRATE TYPE="Rate">2000.00/Nos</OPENINGRATE>
     <CLOSINGRATE TYPE="Rate">1927.69/Nos</CLOSINGRATE>
     <TBALCLOSING TYPE="Amount">-366400.00</TBALCLOSING>
     <TBALOPENING TYPE="Amount">-1000000.00</TBALOPENING>
     <STKOPBALANCE TYPE="Quantity"> 500 Nos</STKOPBALANCE>
     <STKCLBALANCE TYPE="Quantity"> 102 Nos</STKCLBALANCE>
     <TBALDEBITS TYPE="Amount">-2400.00</TBALDEBITS>
     <TBALCREDITS TYPE="Amount">4180000.00</TBALCREDITS>
     <STKINQTY TYPE="Quantity"> 20 Nos</STKINQTY>
     <STKOUTQTY TYPE="Quantity"> 418 Nos</STKOUTQTY>
     <TBALNETTCREDITS TYPE="Amount">4180000.00</TBALNETTCREDITS>
    </STOCKITEM>
    <STOCKITEM NAME="Gas" RESERVEDNAME="">
     <STOCKITEMNAME TYPE="String">Gas</STOCKITEMNAME>
     <CLOSINGBALANCE TYPE="Quantity"></CLOSINGBALANCE>
     <OPENINGBALANCE TYPE="Quantity"></OPENINGBALANCE>
     <DEBITTOTALS TYPE="Quantity"></DEBITTOTALS>
     <CREDITTOTALS TYPE="Quantity"></CREDITTOTALS>
     <OPENINGVALUE TYPE="Amount">0.00</OPENINGVALUE>
     <CLOSINGVALUE TYPE="Amount"></CLOSINGVALUE>
     <OUTWARDVALUE TYPE="Amount"></OUTWARDVALUE>
     <INWARDVALUE TYPE="Amount"></INWARDVALUE>
     <BASICQTY TYPE="Quantity"></BASICQTY>
     <OPENINGRATE TYPE="Rate"></OPENINGRATE>
     <CLOSINGRATE TYPE="Rate"></CLOSINGRATE>
     <TBALCLOSING TYPE="Amount"></TBALCLOSING>
     <TBALOPENING TYPE="Amount">0.00</TBALOPENING>
     <STKOPBALANCE TYPE="Quantity"></STKOPBALANCE>
     <STKCLBALANCE TYPE="Quantity"></STKCLBALANCE>
     <TBALDEBITS TYPE="Amount"></TBALDEBITS>
     <TBALCREDITS TYPE="Amount"></TBALCREDITS>
     <STKINQTY TYPE="Quantity"></STKINQTY>
     <STKOUTQTY TYPE="Quantity"></STKOUTQTY>
     <TBALNETTCREDITS TYPE="Amount"></TBALNETTCREDITS>
    </STOCKITEM>
    ....

   </COLLECTION>
  </DATA>
 </BODY>
</ENVELOPE>
```

this is just only sample it gives very huge amt of data. suppose if i need only  STOCKITEMNAME, CLOSINGBALANCE, STKINQTY  etc ... tag values in json file. this values are in arrays. i tried like this...

```
<?php
.
.
.
$retValue = curl_exec($ch);          
curl_close($ch);
$oXML = simplexml_load_string($retValue );
//echo $sXML;

$hd = array();

foreach ($oXML as $s):
$hd[$s]=$s->DATA->COLLECTION->STOCKITEM;
endforeach;

//$response["error"]                = FALSE;
$response["resp"]               = $hd;
//echo $header;
echo json_encode($response);

?>
```

but this is not working...
help me out please

Comment: What is the returned data of `$oXML`?

Comment: @aldrin27 it returns provided xml as SimpleXMLElement Object. it looks like xml response only but in object format..

Comment: Can i see the object?

Comment: @aldrin27 it is very big cant paste it in comment :(

Comment: @aldrin27 it is  SimpleXMLElement  Object ( [HEADER]=> ([VERSION]=>1[STATUS]=>1)[BODY] =>([DESC]=>([CMPINFO] =>(0]=>))[DATA]=>([COLLECTION]=>([@attributes]=>Array()[STOCKITEM]=>Array([0]=>()[STOCKITEMNAME]=>Abc Test[CLOSINGBALANCE]=>102 Nos....[TBALDEBITS]=>-2400.00[TBALCREDITS]=>4180000.00[STKINQTY]=>20 Nos[STKOUTQTY]=>418 Nos[TBALNETTCREDITS]=>4180000.00))))))

Comment: try `$oXML->DATA->COLLECTION->STOCKITEM;`

Comment: @aldrin27 hey what to do in this case "<MSG.LIST> <MSG>Invalid request</MSG> </MSG.LIST>" to get MSG node value. MSG is child of MSG.LIST.. i tried $hd[1]['MSG'] = (string) $array_data->BODY->DATA->STATUS->MSG.LIST->MSG; but it gives Error type : 4 Message : syntax error, unexpected '->' (T_OBJECT_OPERATOR), expecting '('. I think error is because of "MSG.LIST" . please help me..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`STOCKITEM` element is an array of elements. You have to crab each child element of `STOCKITEM` like `STOCKITEMNAME` etc.

```
<?php
$oXML = simplexml_load_string($retValue);

$i = 0;
$hd = [];
foreach ($oXML->BODY->DATA->COLLECTION->STOCKITEM as $item):
    $hd[$i]['STOCKITEMNAME']= (string) $item->STOCKITEMNAME;
    $hd[$i]['DEBITTOTALS']= (string) $item->DEBITTOTALS;
    # continue with elements you want ...
    $i++;
endforeach;
```

Comment: this is giving output with notice and warnings... E_NOTICE : type 8 -- Trying to get property of non-object -- at line 58
E_WARNING : type 2 -- Invalid argument supplied for foreach() -- at line 58
{"error":false,"resp":{"BODY":{"STOCKITEMNAME":"Gas"}}}   and how to increment $index? it just displaying 1st index value not 0 2 3...

Comment: Ok, i made some edits to my answer. This seems to works.

Comment: hey what to do in this case "<MSG.LIST>
     <MSG>Invalid request</MSG>
    </MSG.LIST>" to get MSG node value. MSG is child of MSG.LIST..  i tried $hd[1]['MSG']  = (string) $array_data->BODY->DATA->STATUS->MSG.LIST->MSG; but it gives Error type : 4 
Message : syntax error, unexpected '->' (T_OBJECT_OPERATOR), expecting '('. I think error is because of "MSG.LIST"